# Why isn't kv binding of the screen change working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I've defined two buttons: one in kv and one in Python. They are located in different screens and are used to navigate between them. What I found strange is that the button that was defined in Python successfully switched the screen, while the one defined in kv did not. Perhaps I'm not accessing the `App` class method properly?
Here is the code of the issue:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string('''
<MyScreen1>:
    Button:
        id: my_bt
        text: "back"
        on_release: app.back
''')


class MyScreen1(Screen):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def here(self, btn):
        self.sm.current = "back"

    def back(self, btn):
        self.sm.current = "here"

    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        s1 = Screen(name = "here")
        bt = Button(text = "here",
                    on_release = self.here)
        s2 = MyScreen1(name = "back")
        #s2.ids['my_bt'].bind(on_release = self.back)
        self.sm.add_widget(s1)
        s1.add_widget(bt)
        self.sm.add_widget(s2)
        return self.sm

TestApp().run()
```

So if I define the switching function in kv (`on_release`), I can't go to the `"here"` screen. But if I uncomment that line in Python and comment the `on_release: app.back` instead, everything works fine.
I'm pretty sure that this is the correct way to access the current app, since it doesn't give me any errors (which means that the method was successfully located)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a subtle difference between kv and python: In kv you actually have to write the [callback as a function call (a python expression)](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords), in this case:

```
on_release: app.back(self)
```